# Linq to custom array object

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, jstree

I am using MVC3/Entity Framework, I need to send a JSON object to be used by a jsTree. The jsTree is calling for the children each time a node is expanded, so each get returns only one set, instead of the whole tree. This is the get function:

```
public ActionResult GetTreeview(string id, string company)
    {
        int parentId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
        var cats = (from x in db.Categories where x.ICG_PARENT_ID == parentId orderby x.ICG_CATEGORY_NAME select new { x.ICG_CATEGORY_ID, x.ICG_PARENT_ID, x.ICG_CATEGORY_NAME }).ToList();
        var jsTree = new JsTreeModel[cats.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < cats.Count; i++)
        {
            jsTree[i] = new JsTreeModel
            {
            data = cats[i].ICG_CATEGORY_NAME, 
            attr = new JsTreeAttribute { id = cats[i].ICG_CATEGORY_ID }, 
            state = "closed"
            };
        }

        return Json(jsTree, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is the model:

```
public class JsTreeModel
{
    public string data;
    public string state;
    public JsTreeAttribute attr;
}

public class JsTreeAttribute
{
    public int id;
    public bool selected;
}
```

I am sure a shorter/better way to do this must exist, but I just recently started learning LINQ and lambda expressions (and MVC) and they are not quite intuitive to me yet. Also, I have been using this site as a resource for a long time (it's wonderful) but this is my first question. Is there really no preview button, or am I blind?

EDIT: Updated Model and Function to change the type of attr.Id to int. LINQ to Entities didn't like string conversion.

Comment: You should ask questions about stackoverflow in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The preview displays at all times at the bottom of the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
public ActionResult GetTreeview(string id, string company)
{
    // company is not being used...
    var parentId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
    var jsTree =
        (from category in db.Categories
         where category.ICG_PARENT_ID == parentId
         orderby category.ICG_CATEGORY_NAME
         select new JsTreeModel
         {
             data = category.ICG_CATEGORY_NAME,
             attr = new JsTreeAttribute { id = category.ICG_CATEGORY_ID.ToString() },
             state = "closed",
         }).ToArray();

    return Json(jsTree, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

---

For the conditional where clause, there's a couple of ways you could do this and they're not going to make much difference in this isolated example.  You could either conditionally use one of two queries that has your where clause:

```
JsTreeModel[] jsTree;
if (parentId == 0)
{
    var companyId = Convert.ToInt32(company);
    jsTree = (from category in db.Categories
              where category.ICG_PARENT_ID == parentId
                 && category.ICG_COMPANY_ID == companyId
              //etc...
             ).ToList();

}
else
{

    jsTree = (from category in db.Categories
              where category.ICG_PARENT_ID == parentId
              //etc..
             ).ToList();
}
```

Or you could break the query where you would have inserted the where clause, conditionally append the additional clause, and finish the query:

```
// get the first part of the query
IQueryable<Category> query = db.Categories
    .Where(category => category.ICG_PARENT_ID == parentId);

// conditionally add the where clause
if (parentId == 0)
{
    var companyId = Convert.ToInt32(company);
    query = query.Where(category => category.ICG_COMPANY_ID == companyId);
}

// finish the query
var jsTree = query
    .OrderBy(category => category.ICG_CATEGORY_NAME)
    .AsEnumerable() // use LINQ to Objects from this point on
    .Select(category => new JsTreeModel
     {
         data = category.ICG_CATEGORY_NAME,
         attr = new JsTreeAttribute { id = category.ICG_CATEGORY_ID.ToString() },
         state = "closed",
     }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Brilliant.
This might be a separate question, but company was unused because I was still looking for a way to conditionally add a where clause. If the id is 0, "Where x.icg_company_id == (int)company" needs to be added, but I couldn't figure that out.

Comment: @user: That could be done rather easily too using a number of different ways.  I'll update my answer to show how you could do that.

Comment: Just a note, your answer maintained x.ICG_CATEGORY_ID, but you had renamed x to category just above.

Comment: @Tyrsius: Yeah I noticed that too.  I inserted that when I saw that you updated your question to include that and forgot to change it.  :)

Comment: In what ways would those different methods make a difference? Is there a standard?

Comment: @Tyrsius: I'd use the first approach if you are generating the query from scratch.  Otherwise, if you have an existing query that you are "adding clauses" to, you'd have to use the second approach.  There's no standard AFAIK, just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: It seems the second method produces an error. I am not sure why this error didn't occur before, actually.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()'

Comment: @Tyrsius: Try changing it from the `ToString()` instance method call to using the static `Convert.ToString()` method.

Comment: I am actually really confused now. The ToString() was working on the original example, now it isn't working on anything, neither does Convert.

Comment: In either case, changing the model type of id to int didn't seem to cause any issues. JSON still accepted it. Thank you very much for your help Jeff

Comment: @Tyrsius: Hmm, that is odd.  I guess the only solution is to explicitly use LINQ to Objects at that point.  I'll update the second part again, let me know if the change fixes it.

Comment: @Jeff I think changing the model type is simpler than a two-step linq. I will just update my question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var jsTree = (from cat in cats
             select new JsTreeModel
             {
                 data = cat.ICG_CATEGORY_NAME, 
                 attr = new JsTreeAttribute { id = cat.ICG_CATEGORY_ID.ToString() }, 
                 state = "closed"
             }).ToArray();
```